# Is this possible to create a single MSI for multiple cultures?

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

Hi I'm using WIX to create multilingual MSI. 
But till now I have created multiple MSI for different - different cultures, Is this at all possible to create sinlgle MSI and once the User clicks on this, at runtime it will decide based on the current user's culture. 
Or is there any other tool which can do this task.

I'm doing this in batch file.

```
candle example.wxs -out example.wixobj
light example.wixobj -cultures:en-us -loc English.wxl -out example-en-us.msi
light example.wixobj -cultures:fr-fr -loc French.wxl -out example-fr-fr.msi
@pause
```

Comment: is this possible without  transform in multilingual.

Answer (score 1):

Check the instructions on the following URL: [Multi-Language MSI Packages without Setup.exe Launcher](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/articles/embeddedlang/index.htm)
It worked perfectly for us with > 20 languages. Just take into account that this mechanism uses language set on the `Standards and formats`-tab in the `Regional settings` of Windows.